# Symfony3.4: How to specify a service with an argument

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony3.4, the following error occurred while supporting automatic wiring.
If you specify the service name with `$articleType` and the existing code that displays the corresponding article, the following error will occur.
Passing multiple services to __construct doesn't work.
Is there any good way?

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html
Controller.php

```php
    private function getArticleSummary($articleType)
    {
        $summary = array();
        $articleService = $this->get('admin.'.$articleType.'Service');
        foreach (array('draft', 'pending', 'reject', 'publish', 'hidden') as $articleStatus) {
            $params = array(
                'articleType' => $articleType,
                'articleStatus' => $articleStatus,
            );
            $summary[$articleStatus] = $articleService->countArticleBySearchParams($params);
        }
        return $summary;
    }
```

services.yml

```yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    App\:
        resource: '../../src/*'
        exclude: '../../src/{Entity,Repository, Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Resources/public/uploadify, Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Ahi/Sp/PublicBundle/ }'

    App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/Ahi/Sp/AdminBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    admin.brandeventService:
      autowire: true
      autoconfigure: true
      class: 'App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\BrandEventService'

    App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\Hq\DefaultController:
      arguments: [ '@admin.brandeventService' ]

    App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\BrandEventService: '@admin.brandeventService'
```

Error in the current code

```
Service "admin.brandeventService" not found:  
even though it exists in the app's container,  
the container inside "App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\Hq\DefaultController"  
is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine"
```

Tried code

- Add $brandEventService to __construct of articleService
- Add __construct and $brandEventService to DefaultController
- Set service in DefaultController in services.yml
- Added BrandEventService $brandEventService to getArticleSummary

DefaultController.php

```php
    protected $brandEventService;

    public function __construct(BrandEventService $brandEventService)
    {
        $this->brandEventService = $brandEventService;
    }
```

Tried result of `php bin/console debug:container admin.brandeventService`

```
Information for Service "admin.brandeventService"
=================================================

 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------------- 
  Option           Value                                                   
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------------- 
  Service ID       admin.brandeventService                                 
  Class            App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\BrandEventService  
  Tags             -                                                       
  Public           no                                                      
  Synthetic        no                                                      
  Lazy             no                                                      
  Shared           yes                                                     
  Abstract         no                                                      
  Autowired        yes                                                     
  Autoconfigured   yes                                                     
 ---------------- --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Now you are getting to the fun stuff.  Under 3.4, using the AbstractController, only a limited number of services are available using $this->get().  There are a couple of options.  The best is to make yourself a service locator for your article type services.  You can read about locators in the docs though they can be a bit tricky to configure properly.  In the short term it might be better to just inject the container and pull the services directly from it.  Need to make sure they are defined as public.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you for your comment. There is a method called service locator. After that, create __construct in the controller and put the service in it. By the way, what does it mean to be defined as public?

Comment: Services accessible via $service = $container->get('service') must be defined as public.  By default services are defined as private which means you can only access them via injection.  But if you got the service locator configuration working then great.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you. As I wrote in the text, I added __construct to the Controller, but I got the same error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe you could create an `ArticleServiceFactory` which you can inject and let it create the correct service you need via the `create($articleType)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is based on the context of the question.  The goal is here is updating a legacy Symfony 2 app ultimately to 4.4.  Trying to get the code running under 3.4 without rewriting too much of the app.

The basic issue is that when using Symfony's AbstractController class, only specific services can be accessed using $this->get().  You can look at the source code to see what is going on but essentially the ServiceSubscriberInterface::getSubscribedServices() method is used to specify which services are available.  So the quickest way to get past this problem is to add the article type services to your derived controller:

```
class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    public static function getSubscribedServices() : array
    {
        $services = parent::getSubscribedServices();

        $services['admin.brand'] = BrandEventService::class;
        $services['admin.other'] = OtherEventService::class;

        return $services;
    }
    public function type(string $type = null) : Response
    {
        $serviceId = 'admin.' . $type;
        $service = $this->get($serviceId);
        return new Response('Article Type ' . $type);
    }
```

The above code shows adding two services to the controller's service locator and then pulling one of them in an action method.  The services.yaml file is just the basic out of the box configuration.  No aliases or tweaks are needed.  It should be enough to get you going.

Once you understand what is going on here then you can go back and read the section on service locators and perhaps understand the 'correct' way of handling this problem.  But that could actually wait until you get to 4.4 as there are some refinements introduced in Symfony 4.

Comment: Oh. The code I received magically cleared the error and allowed me to move on to the next step. If it works up to Symfony 4.4, it's even more secure. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your `services.yaml` like this:

```yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true

  admin.shopeventService:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: true
    class: App\Admin\Media\Provider\MultiUploadFileProvider

    # ...

    App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\ShopEventService: '@admin.shopeventService'


    # same here
    # ...
   App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\BrandEventService: '@admin.brandeventService'
```

For more details you can see this link https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#using-aliases-to-enable-autowiring

Hope that is helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, when I tried it, I got the same error.

Comment: Try to debug step by step. 
First of all, try run `php bin/console container debug your_service.id` and be sure that you have a correct `services.yaml`

Comment: I've added commands and services, can you see?

Comment: In your services.yaml , set `public: true` and let see this time :)
(I modify my first response to make this more clear)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I tried "public: true" but got a similar error.
I tried the previous command and confirmed that it was public.

Comment: Make sure that `'admin.'.$articleType.'Service'` is awlays `"admin.brandeventService"` or the second service :)

Comment: I'm trying to switch services (there are 4 or more) depending on ```$articleType```. Also, since this error appears from the login screen, it is difficult to verify whether it will be another ```$articleType``` as a function. Does this match your instructions?

Comment: Folks - Just wanted to point out that with a 3.4 AbstractController you are not dealing with the actual container.  Only certain services are available from inside of the controller class.  No amount of tweaking will make this approach work.  That is what the original error message is trying to tell you.